# R Shiny: is there an option for turning off reactive components?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I would like to turn off Shiny's reactive UI entirely.  Is there a way to achieve that with a single option switch?

I found [some articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611254/r-shiny-disable-able-shinyui-elements) that discuss piecewise approaches for switching off reactivity.  But is there a more general switch for turning off reactivity entirely for whole Shiny Server?

This may sound like a feature request that begs the question of why I am using Shiny at all.  Our use-case is simple:  graph data pulled from a backend database, and parameterize the data pulled with values set in Shiny UI components in a non-reactive manner.

In short, we enjoy the bonus of Shiny's plotting capabilities through R along with Shiny's nice UI components, but we forgo the reactive behavior in favor of HTML-like forms that parameterize the graphs.

Comment: I wonder exactly the same..in wanting a bunch of unreactive inputs (eg date and data class fields to choose from to query/group/plot that are non reactive until clicking one action button, which just queries/filters the one `data.frame` and passes it on to eg ggplot/plotly/leaflet functions for nice data vis. Especially when the querying and plotting isn't quick. From what I could tell it seemed a wrapper like `isolate()`,`eventReactive()`, or `observeEvent()` might be needed in many places in the way my `app.r` is set up with a good amount of if statements and plot types.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Showing UI elements in disabled state by default, so that the user can't modify them? Or simply disregard whatever change the users make within the UI?