# Disabling fileInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have one `selectizeInput` and one `fileInput` in my **shiny app**.

I want to keep `fileInput` disabled until some value is not selected in `selectizeInput`.

Also I want a **popup message** to select a value every time user clicks on `fileInput`.
How can I do that.

Comment: The `shinyjs` package has a show/hide feature. You can hide the file selector until your condition is satisfied. Take a look at https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny

Comment: in the same package, you should look at the ```disable``` function, as used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611254/r-shiny-disable-able-shinyui-elements)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the `shinyjs` package is useful here.  You could use `enable`, `disable`, or `toggleState`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    selectizeInput("selector", label="Choose 2:", multiple=TRUE,
                   choices=letters[1:5], selected=letters[1:5]),
    fileInput("file_inputer", label="upload file")#,
    # dataTableOutput('table') 
)

server = function(input, output) {
    observe({
        shinyjs::toggleState("file_inputer", length(input$selector) %in% 0:4)
    })

    observeEvent(input$file_inputer, {
        showModal(modalDialog(
           title="Do you want a header row?",
           selectInput("option_selector", label="Choose an option",
                       choices=c("option 1", "option 2", "option 3")),
           footer = tagList(actionButton("read_file", "Read File"),
                            modalButton("Cancel")
           )
        ))
    })

    observeEvent(input$read_file, {
        # do something with your option value
        removeModal()
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The button does not appear disabled even if it is. I think the problem is that the button does not have the id but the input does.

Comment: Seems you can achieve that by adding `runjs('$("#file_inputer").parents("span").addClass("disabled")')` with the appropriate condition.

Comment: @JanStanstrup can you clarify where this runjs() statement needs to go?

Comment: Don't worry - I figured it out - it's just after the disable(file_inputer) but as an annoyance, if your code is modularised, the runjs() needs an input specific to the module i.e. id-file-inputer